# How to add "ng-model" in DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

**I am working in asp.net MVC4 with angularJs. I am trying to add an "ng-model" to dropdownlist. My DropDownListis like this:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("UnitConversionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UnitConversionId, "No Unit Seleced", new { ng-model="newItem.UnitConversionId" })
```

**I also tried this. But I am getting an error:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("UnitConversionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UnitConversionId, "No Unit Seleced", new { @ng-model="newItem.UnitConversionId" })
```

**Is there any way to add an "ng-model" to DropDownList?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get any kind of attribute that contains a dash (so also all kinds of HTML5 data attributes) to render by changing the dash to underscore in the definition:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UnitConversionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UnitConversionId, "No Unit Seleced", new { ng_model="newItem.UnitConversionId" })
```